# CSRF Fails after setting up Django app on Apache

Tags: django, apache, ssl, mod-wsgi

After creating app in django and ensuring that everything works i tried to serve my app on remote server. The stack over there is Apache with mod-wsgi-py3. After setting up Apache with documentation provided by mod_wsgi i am having problems with mod-wsgi

To make sure that i dont have any problem with my app i checked on standard admin page in Django. The only open domain from that server to access is 'https://app.web.corpnet.pl:15003/app/' so all my uri's use this as a root.

I think that the problem is either in django settings (allowed hosts?) or apache conf so im pasting these:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', 'app.tnweb.corpnet.pl', 
            'app.tnweb.corpnet.pl:15003', 'app.corpnet.pl', 'corpnet.pl']
```

Problem is described by django debug as:

Forbidden (403)

CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
Help

Reason given for failure:
    Referer checking failed - https://app.tnweb.corpnet.pl:15003/app/admin/login/?next=/app/admin/ does not match any trusted origin

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring a SECRET_KEY:
'app.config[‘SECRET_KEY’]=‘aSecretAndComplexString’'

Usualy CSRF verification method fails if no secret key is declared.